# Best way to create substitution macros in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'd like to set up some custom auto-complete macros in vim. I'm thinking something like this (`|` represents the cursor position):

```
it<TAB>|
```

immediately becomes:

```
it("|", function () {
});
```

Is this possible using straight vim, or would I need a plugin? If so, is there a preferred plugin out there?

Comment: I will go for ultisnips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an abbreviation you could write something like this:

```
inorea it it("", function () {<cr>});<c-o>k<c-o>f"
```

The purpose of `<c-o>k<c-o>f"` at the end is to reposition your cursor inside the double quotes, but it may not work all the time.

---

Using a mapping, you could try this:

```
ino <expr> <tab> <sid>expand_last_word()

let s:your_expansions = {
                        \ 'it': '\<c-w>it(\"\", function () {\<cr>});\<c-o>k\<right>',
                        \ }

fu! s:expand_last_word() abort
    let last_word = matchstr(getline('.'), '\v<\k+%'.col('.').'c')
    return has_key(s:your_expansions, last_word)
                \ ? eval('"'.s:your_expansions[last_word].'"')
                \ : "\<tab>"
endfu
```

You would have to add your abbreviations and their expansions inside the dictionary `s:your_expansions`.

---

Using the `:read` command, you could define larger snippets of code, and split them across several files:

```
ino <expr> <tab> <sid>expand_last_word()

fu! s:expand_last_word() abort
    let last_word = matchstr(getline('.'), '\v<\k+%'.col('.').'c')
    if last_word ==# 'it'
        return "\<c-w>\<c-o>:r /path/to/some_file\<cr>\<c-o>f\"\<right>"
    endif
    return "\<tab>"
endfu
```

Here `/path/to/some_file` should contain your snippet:

```
it("", function () {
});
```

---

They are very simple solutions, if you want something more robust, you probably need a snippets plugin. One of them is [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), which requires that your Vim version has been compiled with Python support (`:echo has('python')` or `:echo has('python3')` returns 1).

With UltiSnips, you would write your snippet like this:

```
snippet it "your description" b
it("$0", function () {
});
endsnippet
```

Here the definition is included between the keywords `snippet` and `endsnippet`. On the 1st line, you can describe the purpose of your snippet, inside the string in double quotes. It will be displayed by UltiSnips inside a list, if you've defined several snippets with the same tab trigger, and there's an ambiguity.

The ending `b` is an option to prevent the tab trigger `it` from being expanded anywhere else than the beginning of a line.

`$0` is a tabstop, it stands for the position in which you want the cursor to be, once the snippet has been fully expanded.

The readme page on github gives a quick start, and some links to videos.

If you want to have a look at the snippets written by other people, you can install [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets).

There are other snippet managers but I don't know them well enough to describe the syntax of their snippets. If you want a comparison, here's [one](http://vim-wiki.mawercer.de/wiki/topic/text-snippets-skeletons-templates.html), and here are links for some of them:

- [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)
- [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template)
- [neosnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim)
- [xptemplate](https://github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `abbreviation` that you can use for your particular example

```
:inoreabbrev it it("", function () {<cr>});<esc>kf"a
```

Typing `it` followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> in insert mode will render

```
it("|", function () {
});
```

and keep you in insert mode.

But I would definitely go for [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) and there is a [screencast](http://www.sirver.net/blog/2012/01/08/second-episode-of-ultisnips-screencast/) for creating snippets on the same page. That's why I am omitting the snippet here as you can do it yourself.